# From a Future List to a Stream List Flutter Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I am trying to create a stream of a list containing Firebase documents.
This is my current function:

```dart
Future<List<Service>> getServicesById(id) async {
  List<Service> services = [];
  for (String ids in id) {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('Services')
      .doc(ids)
      .get()
      .then((value) {
        services.add(Service.fromJson(value.data()!));
       });
  }

  return services;
}
```

How can I transfer this into a stream, returning the list of services?

Comment: FYI, the above code doesn't properly return a `Future<List<Service>>` either.  It will return `services` immediately (while it's still empty) before any of the asynchronous operations complete.

Comment: You have only one item.  Why do you want a Stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your method like this:

```dart
Stream<Service> getServicesById(List<String> ids) async* {
  for (String id in ids) {
    final DocumentSnapshot document = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Services')
        .doc(id)
        .get();

    yield Service.fromJson(document.data()!);
  }
}
```

If you want to return them at once:

```dart
Stream<List<Service>> getServicesById(List<String> ids) async* {
  List<Service> services = [];

  for (String id in ids) {
    final DocumentSnapshot document = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Services')
        .doc(id)
        .get();

    if (document.exists) {
      services.add(Service.fromJson(document.data()!));
    }
  }

  // Yield the list of services when the loop is done
  yield services;
}
```

Comment: NP @Andrei :) ...

Comment: Both of your examples returns a Stream with exactly only one element, and terminates.  What's the point of a Stream if there's only one event?  Maybe you wanted Future instead?

Comment: @RandalSchwartz the first example yields a stream of services.